# NDepend, TestDriven and HostType

Tags: unit-testing, testdriven.net, ndepend

I'm making use of the TestDriven.NET plugin for visual studio to run all my tests to check for code coverage with NDepend. All is working fine apart from my tests with a HostType attribute. These aren't getting run.

Does anybody knopw how to fix this or is there a specific reason for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try to run those tests?

Comment: Those tests run fine, both on their own and when running all the tests in the solution using the inbuilt test runners, its only when using run tests with -> NDepend

Comment: Which code coverage technology (NCover, VS), test impl (NUnit, MS test) are you using? What do you mean by 'using run tests with -> NDepend' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the release notes for TestDriven.NET, they explicitly skip test with the HostType attribute. I'm not sure why they do this exactly.

I can actually not find another test runner outside of the built in runner in Visual Studio that will execute those tests, Resharper/dotCover gives me an Aborted message when running a specific test with a HostType

EDIT: Linked to release notes (look at item 3203) http://www.testdriven.net/downloads/releasenotes.html